# Почему фигуры не накладываются друг на друга?

Tags: z-index, css

Почему фигуры не накладываются друг на друга?
Задача: сделать полупрозрачную рамку в 5px.
[КОД](http://jsfiddle.net/0gd0254m/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не накладываются, потому что `position:relative` у обоих. А полупрозрачный бордер лучше сделать [вот так](http://jsfiddle.net/g4wnLmrj/).